# Consistent string sorting between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, stdstring

On server side (C#) I sort an array of strings and send it to client (C++) that then does binary searches on that string array (`vector<wstring>).`

I would like to make sure that array is sorted in C#, the same way it would be sorted in C++. Otherwise, binary search might fail in some cases.

If I understand correctly, C++ `wstring`s are sorted by default according to ordinal positions of their caracters in Unicode table. So I am assuming sort with `StringComparison.Ordinal` would be appropriate?

Comment: Have you tried sorting with `StringComparison.Ordinal` option in server side (C#)?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is working in cases I have tested, but I wanted to double check if it is guaranteed to works, since the code has to work with different languages.